# Como transformar conteúdo de um arquivo em um array no PHP

Tags: php, javascript, array, regex, file-get-contents

Tenho um arquivo que tem um `array` com as traduções de um site.

**O conteúdo do arquivo é similar a esse:**

```
var textHome = {
    "home": {
        "btn_contact": {
            "pt": "contato",
            "en": "contact",
        },
        "btn_home": {
            "pt": "Início",
            "en": "Home",
        },
        "bt_about": {
            "pt": "Sobre nós",
            "en": "About us",
        },
    }
};
```

Gostaria de ler esse arquivo no php e transformar em um array, colocar em uma variável e pegar um idioma específico pra adicionar ao conteúdo do site. Ta ser necessário usar **REGEX** para remover o "var textHome" e limpar algo mais desnecessário. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Pq não lê como JavaScript mesmo e pega o objeto que deseja dentro de `textHome`?

Comment: Preciso colocar no PHP por causa das buscas do Google.

Comment: não é só escrever ele direto na página pelo script do js? `<?php echo '<script></script>'?>`

Comment: Tenho vários lugares que preciso colocar os textos. E tenho que usar uma variável no PHP pra poder pegar o conteúdo.

Comment: Faz um split pelo "=" que você tem a string de objetos. creio que com essa estrutura, dê para usar um json_decode(), testa ai

Comment: E por que não muda manualmente esse arquivo para um padrão que seja suportado no PHP? Analisar dinamicamente esse arquivo será uma gambiarra gigantesca (ou demandará uma implementação muito bem estruturada, que provavelmente não será o caso). Existem padrões específicos, inclusive, para traduções. Por que não os utiliza?

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro você precisa pegar o conteúdo do arquivo:

Vamos supor que o arquivo se chama `meu_js.js` e fica na raiz da aplicação:

```
$file = file_get_contents('meu_js.js');
```

Lembre-se de usar o seu arquivo no método.

Feito isso você precisa separa a declaração da variável do JSON:

```
$arr = explode('=',$file);
```

Isso te retornará um vetor com duas posições:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'var textHome ' (length=13)
  1 => string ' {
    "home": {
        "btn_contact": {
            "pt": "contato",
            "en": "contact",
        },
        "btn_home": {
            "pt": "Início",
            "en": "Home",
        },
        "bt_about": {
            "pt": "Sobre nós",
            "en": "About us",
        },
    }
};' (length=317)
```

A primeira posição não nos interessa, mas a segunda sim. É o nosso JSON. Precisamos agora transformá-lo em um vetor.

Um ponto importante a ser notado é que esse seu JSON é invalido e não será decodificado pelo PHP. Veja o por que:

```
{
    "home": {
        "btn_contact": {
            "pt": "contato",
            "en": "contact",\\ <-- essa virgula torna o json inválido. O ultimo atributo do json não deve ter virgula
        },
        "btn_home": {
            "pt": "Início",
            "en": "Home",\\ <-- essa virgula torna o json inválido. O ultimo atributo do json não deve ter virgula
        },
        "bt_about": {
            "pt": "Sobre nós",
            "en": "About us",\\ <-- essa virgula torna o json inválido. O ultimo atributo do json não deve ter virgula
        },\\ <-- essa virgula torna o json inválido. O ultimo atributo do json não deve ter virgula
    }
};\\ <-- como extraímos o json separando a string pelo "=" esse ";" também torna o JSON inválido.
```

Precisamos limpar o JSON para que seja lido corretamente. Temos duas opções aqui, garantir sempre a escrita correta do JSON ou usar regex. Eu vou passar aqui as REGEX utilizadas para limpar especificamente o formato que você usou. Dependendo da estrutura do JSON essa REGEX pode não funcionar corretamente:

```
$json_str = str_replace(';','',$arr[1]);
```

Aqui removemos o `;` do final do arquivo

```
$json_str = preg_replace('/(\},\s*\}\s*\})/','}}}',$json_str);
```

Aqui, nós buscamos a ocorrência de `},   }   }`:

- `\}` - o fechamento da chave;
- `,` - seguido de uma virgula;
- `\s*` - seguido de zero ou mais espaços;
- `\}` - seguido de outro fechamento de chave;
- `\s*` - seguido de zero ou mais espaços;
- `\}` - seguido de outro fechamento de chave;

E substituímos por `}}}` removendo assim a virgula em

```
        },
    }
}
```

Por fim, vamos substituir as virgulas dentro dos atributos com uma expressão similar:

```
$json_str = preg_replace('/(\",\s*\})/','"}',$json_str);
```

Aqui, nós estamos buscando por `",    }` e substituindo por `"}`

- `\"` - Aspas duplas literais;
- `\s` - zero ou mais espaços;
- `\}` - fechamento de chaves literal;

Agora, é só decodificar o JSON e utilizá-lo:

```
$json = json_decode($json_str);
var_dump($json);

object(stdClass)[5]
  public 'home' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'btn_contact' => 
        object(stdClass)[1]
          public 'pt' => string 'contato' (length=7)
          public 'en' => string 'contact' (length=7)
      public 'btn_home' => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'pt' => string 'Início' (length=7)
          public 'en' => string 'Home' (length=4)
      public 'bt_about' => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'pt' => string 'Sobre nós' (length=10)
          public 'en' => string 'About us' (length=8)
```

Lembrando que isso irá transformar o JSON em objeto. Caso queira array decodifique com:

```
$json = json_decode($json_str,true);
```

Algumas leituras recomendadas:

- https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php
- https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html